# How to determine Delphi Application Version

Tags: delphi, version

Want to obtain Delphi Application build number and post into title bar

Comment: I see most proposed answers make use of GetFileVersion. There are issues with this option, I've posted the details in an answer of my own.

Answer (score 34):

Here is how I do it. I put this in almost all of my small utilities:

```
procedure GetBuildInfo(var V1, V2, V3, V4: word);
var
  VerInfoSize, VerValueSize, Dummy: DWORD;
  VerInfo: Pointer;
  VerValue: PVSFixedFileInfo;
begin
  VerInfoSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(ParamStr(0)), Dummy);
  if VerInfoSize > 0 then
  begin
      GetMem(VerInfo, VerInfoSize);
      try
        if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(ParamStr(0)), 0, VerInfoSize, VerInfo) then
        begin
          VerQueryValue(VerInfo, '\', Pointer(VerValue), VerValueSize);
          with VerValue^ do
          begin
            V1 := dwFileVersionMS shr 16;
            V2 := dwFileVersionMS and $FFFF;
            V3 := dwFileVersionLS shr 16;
            V4 := dwFileVersionLS and $FFFF;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        FreeMem(VerInfo, VerInfoSize);
      end;
  end;
end;

function GetBuildInfoAsString: string;
var
  V1, V2, V3, V4: word;
begin
  GetBuildInfo(V1, V2, V3, V4);
  Result := IntToStr(V1) + '.' + IntToStr(V2) + '.' +
    IntToStr(V3) + '.' + IntToStr(V4);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Caption := Form1.Caption + ' - v' + GetBuildInfoAsString;
end;
```

Comment: Mick, you should check the returned VerInfoSize like Joseph, and only pursue if > 0, as it may not have file version informastion.

Comment: A try...finally would not be bad either for the GetMem/FreeMem

Comment: I just added the try...finally.

Comment: Mick, as i can see your code will not compile since there was no declaration of sFileName variable in your snippet.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to the posts above, I made my own library for this purpose.

I believe that it is a little bit more correct than all other solutions here, so I share it - feel free to reuse it...

```
unit KkVersion;

interface

function FileDescription: String;
function LegalCopyright: String;
function DateOfRelease: String; // Proprietary
function ProductVersion: String;
function FileVersion: String;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Math;

(*
  function GetHeader(out AHdr: TVSFixedFileInfo): Boolean;

  var
  BFixedFileInfo: PVSFixedFileInfo;
  RM: TMemoryStream;
  RS: TResourceStream;
  BL: Cardinal;

  begin
  Result := False;
  RM := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
  RS := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(HInstance, 1, RT_VERSION);
  try
  RM.CopyFrom(RS, RS.Size);
  finally
  FreeAndNil(RS);
  end;

  // Extract header
  if not VerQueryValue(RM.Memory, '\\', Pointer(BFixedFileInfo), BL) then
  Exit;

  // Prepare result
  CopyMemory(@AHdr, BFixedFileInfo, Math.Min(sizeof(AHdr), BL));
  Result := True;
  finally
  FreeAndNil(RM);
  end;
  end;
*)

function GetVersionInfo(AIdent: String): String;

type
  TLang = packed record
    Lng, Page: WORD;
  end;

  TLangs = array [0 .. 10000] of TLang;

  PLangs = ^TLangs;

var
  BLngs: PLangs;
  BLngsCnt: Cardinal;
  BLangId: String;
  RM: TMemoryStream;
  RS: TResourceStream;
  BP: PChar;
  BL: Cardinal;
  BId: String;

begin
  // Assume error
  Result := '';

  RM := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // Load the version resource into memory
    RS := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(HInstance, 1, RT_VERSION);
    try
      RM.CopyFrom(RS, RS.Size);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(RS);
    end;

    // Extract the translations list
    if not VerQueryValue(RM.Memory, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation', Pointer(BLngs), BL) then
      Exit; // Failed to parse the translations table
    BLngsCnt := BL div sizeof(TLang);
    if BLngsCnt <= 0 then
      Exit; // No translations available

    // Use the first translation from the table (in most cases will be OK)
    with BLngs[0] do
      BLangId := IntToHex(Lng, 4) + IntToHex(Page, 4);

    // Extract field by parameter
    BId := '\\StringFileInfo\\' + BLangId + '\\' + AIdent;
    if not VerQueryValue(RM.Memory, PChar(BId), Pointer(BP), BL) then
      Exit; // No such field

    // Prepare result
    Result := BP;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(RM);
  end;
end;

function FileDescription: String;
begin
  Result := GetVersionInfo('FileDescription');
end;

function LegalCopyright: String;
begin
  Result := GetVersionInfo('LegalCopyright');
end;

function DateOfRelease: String;
begin
  Result := GetVersionInfo('DateOfRelease');
end;

function ProductVersion: String;
begin
  Result := GetVersionInfo('ProductVersion');
end;

function FileVersion: String;
begin
  Result := GetVersionInfo('FileVersion');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you - I have voted you up because you did not fall into the trap of assuming the locale is $0409 (Unites States English). It isn't on my Delphi XE7, and I'm sure for the majority of Delphi developers

Comment: @DaveBoltman Yeah, mine is always set to South African English for all of my Delphi projects.

Comment: @ShaunRoselt - "South African English" - yea mine too!! Greetings from Krugersdorp

Answer (score 22):

I most strongly recommend not to use GetFileVersion when you want to know the version of the executable that is currently running! I have two pretty good reasons to do this:

1. The executable may be unaccessible (disconnected drive/share), or changed (.exe renamed to .bak and replaced by a new .exe without the running process being stopped).
2. The version data you're trying to read has actually already been loaded into memory, and is available to you by loading this resource, which is always better than to perform extra (relatively slow) disk operations.

To load the version resource in Delphi I use code like this:

```
uses Windows,Classes,SysUtils;
var
  verblock:PVSFIXEDFILEINFO;
  versionMS,versionLS:cardinal;
  verlen:cardinal;
  rs:TResourceStream;
  m:TMemoryStream;
  p:pointer;
  s:cardinal;
begin
  m:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    rs:=TResourceStream.CreateFromID(HInstance,1,RT_VERSION);
    try
      m.CopyFrom(rs,rs.Size);
    finally
      rs.Free;
    end;
    m.Position:=0;
    if VerQueryValue(m.Memory,'\',pointer(verblock),verlen) then
      begin
        VersionMS:=verblock.dwFileVersionMS;
        VersionLS:=verblock.dwFileVersionLS;
        AppVersionString:=Application.Title+' '+
          IntToStr(versionMS shr 16)+'.'+
          IntToStr(versionMS and $FFFF)+'.'+
          IntToStr(VersionLS shr 16)+'.'+
          IntToStr(VersionLS and $FFFF);
      end;
    if VerQueryValue(m.Memory,PChar('\\StringFileInfo\\'+
      IntToHex(GetThreadLocale,4)+IntToHex(GetACP,4)+'\\FileDescription'),p,s) or
        VerQueryValue(m.Memory,'\\StringFileInfo\\040904E4\\FileDescription',p,s) then //en-us
          AppVersionString:=PChar(p)+' '+AppVersionString;
  finally
    m.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'll vote this up if you make the code exception-safe with regard to memory and resource allocations.

Comment: I've added try-finally's, should do the trick. In case you were wondering what the TMemoryStream's for: VerQueryValue had trouble reading from rs.Memory directory...

Comment: If resources are anything like they were in my API days, they aren't already in memory, but are fetched from the file. Also, it would be unusual to be doing a swap underneath the app, so I don't think it worth worrying about for most people.

Comment: There's nothing unusual about renaming a running executable, it's the accepted workaround for Windows' inability to overwrite it. Update routines often rename the running executable to be able to copy the new version to the original location.

Comment: This is an awful lot of code just to extract version info.

There should be something simple, like just calling a function (for example get **majorversion**) in the RTTI....

Comment: He wants to post the build # into the title bar. To me, that means the application is looking at it's own version information. So part of your scenario #1 is not valid; the EXE will always have access to itself. It might have been renamed though; that is a good point.

Comment: There's a bug in Delphi that is exposed by the code. The `Name` of the resource you're asking for is `PChar(1)`. If the resource is not found (i.e. there is no version information), Delphi will try to throw an `EResNotFound` (*Resource %s not found*). When it tries to build a string using `PChar` `0x00000001` it will trigger an access violation, as there are no ansi chars to be read at address $00000001.

Comment: Also doesn't work unless the locale is $0409 (Unites States English) - Not a reliable assumption over the world's population of Delphi developers - otherwise good answer

Comment: @DaveBoltman, the Delphi Project Properties Dialog has a Locale selection drop-down for which to add the version data. It's indeed required to select 'English (United States)' there, or use the selected Locale ID in above code.

Answer (score 13):

Pass the full file name of your EXE to this function, and it will return a string like:
2.1.5.9, or whatever your version # is.

```
function GetFileVersion(exeName : string): string;
const
  c_StringInfo = 'StringFileInfo\040904E4\FileVersion';
var
  n, Len : cardinal;
  Buf, Value : PChar;
begin
  Result := '';
  n := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(exeName),n);
  if n > 0 then begin
    Buf := AllocMem(n);
    try
      GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(exeName),0,n,Buf);
      if VerQueryValue(Buf,PChar(c_StringInfo),Pointer(Value),Len) then begin
        Result := Trim(Value);
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(Buf,n);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

After defining that, you can use it to set your form's caption like so:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  //ParamStr(0) is the full path and file name of the current application
  Form1.Caption := Form1.Caption + ' version ' + GetFileVersion(ParamStr(0));
end;
```

Comment: Joseph, you should protect your AllocMem with a try...finally

Comment: @Wodzu: it works for me in D2007.  Does your project have the "Include version information in project" option checked under Project->Options->Version Info?  What does Windows Explorer tell you the file version is?

Comment: This doesn't work unless your locale is $0409  (United States English) - not a reliable assumption

Comment: Working very well with Delphi 10.1 (Berlin). :)

Comment: @DaveBoltman, you are right, thanks for pointing that out.  User Jiri Krivanek has another version below, which claims to avoid the locale issue.  I haven't tried it, but it might be a better fit for you.  Alternatively, you could just change the "040904E4" in my code to the locale you need.

Answer (score 3):

We do this for all our apps but we use a Raize component RzVersioninfo.
works quite well just need to use the following code

on form create

```
Caption := RzVersioninfo1.filedescripion + ': '  + RzVersionInfo1.FileVersion;
```

obviously if you don't want any of the other components from raize use one of the options above as there is a cost to the raize components.

Comment: I like this method due to it being so simple and short.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/delphi/delphi.html#AppVersion

> With this function you can get the version of a file, which contains a
>   version resource. This way you can display the version number of your
>   application in an information dialog. To include a version resource to
>   your Delphi application, set the "Versioninfo" in the project options.

Comment: Good link, but lousy answer. Please summarize the contents of the link: What kind of solution should we expect to find by following the link, and what are the important functions to pay attention to?

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
uses unit Winapi.Windows;

function GetModuleVersion(Instance: THandle; out iMajor, iMinor, iRelease, iBuild: Integer): Boolean;
var
    fileInformation: PVSFIXEDFILEINFO;
    verlen: Cardinal;
    rs: TResourceStream;
    m: TMemoryStream;
begin

   result := false;

    m := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
        try
          rs := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(Instance, 1, RT_VERSION);
          try
              m.CopyFrom(rs, rs.Size);
          finally
              rs.Free;
          end;
        except
          exit;
        end;

        m.Position:=0;
        if not VerQueryValue(m.Memory, '\', Pointer(fileInformation), verlen) then
        begin
          iMajor := 0;
          iMinor := 0;
          iRelease := 0;
          iBuild := 0;
          Exit;
        end;

        iMajor := fileInformation.dwFileVersionMS shr 16;
        iMinor := fileInformation.dwFileVersionMS and $FFFF;
        iRelease := fileInformation.dwFileVersionLS shr 16;
        iBuild := fileInformation.dwFileVersionLS and $FFFF;
    finally
        m.Free;
    end;

    Result := True;
end;
```

Usage:

```
  if GetModuleVersion(HInstance, iMajor, iMinor, iRelease, iBuild) then
    ProgramVersion := inttostr(iMajor)+'.'+inttostr(iMinor)+'.'+inttostr(iRelease)+'.'+inttostr(iBuild);
```