# Programmatically increase Version number in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

I was looking how to retrieve the Version number and found this:

[How to determine Delphi Application Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717844/how-to-determine-delphi-application-version)

All good and works fine, but, D6 only increments that after a Build. Is there any way to increment that number after a Compile? When tweaking small-changes it would be nice to have that increment with just a compile too.

Comment: The IDE doesn't support this in any version. Are you sure this is what you want to do? *Declare a new variable J. Add a loop using it. Compile. (Version increase.) Add two new lines of code, change one. Compile. (Version increase.) Add a new method. Compile. (Version increase.)* Seems to me this should be something that version numbers in your VCS should handle, with versions changing when you check in code, with log entries to explain *signficant* changes.

Comment: opensource mrExpert for Delphi 5 used to add compilation time into project's Version Info - I think you can find it and learn form it's sources

Comment: I don't see why you would want to do this. There's a reason it only increments on `build` and not a `compile`.

Comment: To manipulate the version numbers programatically at design time, after, or in conjunction with, a compile, you would use the OTA (Open Tools Api). The topic is though, **far too broad** to be answered in details here at Stack Overflow. I removed my answer, because it collected downvotes, probably because the reference to manual change or suggestion of always doing a build (instead of compile), or maybe because of the non-detailed reference to using OTA, who knows.